# Using server sent events with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, progress-bar, server-sent-events

I've been trying to set up a progress bar using server sent events, but I can't seem to find a way to set the headers to text/stream using laravel without making and returning a response, if I have something like this:

```
Controller {

    public function doStuff()
    {
        $this->doer->doLengthyStuff();
    }
}

doer {

    public function doLenghtyStuff()
    {
        //doing stuff

        echo $progress;
        flush();
    }
}
```

How do I set the headers to be text/stream on the doer class?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding progress event listener using jquery ajax xhr and simply echoing and flushing messages server side.